# How many different graphs are there of the form: $G=(V,E)$ and $V=\{1,...,n \} $.

Tags: graph-theory

> How many different graphs are there of the form: $G=(V,E)$  and
>   $V=\{1,...,n \} $.

This is what I thought:

$E$ is a set containing the lines which are $2$-element sets. There $\binom n 2$ different ways to get such a set, so I think this must be the answer. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You're on the right track, that's how many edges are possible.  Now how many graphs can be built from those edges?

Comment: @vadim123 A line is either part of the graph or not. So then 2 times $\binom n 2 $ ?

Comment: Consider each edge.

Comment: Nitpicky comment: Though it is essentially clear, you should add that you are talking about simple graphs here.  There are countably many multigraphs on a set of $n \geq 2$ vertices.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $^nC_2$ is the number of edges possible. Now consider forming graphs from these edges.

(You may or may not take any particular edge.)

Answer (score 2):

To give this question a complete answer: in any graph with vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ possible edges.  To construct a graph, for each of these possible edges, we can choose to include it or not.  Hence there are $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ distinct graphs on the vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Equivalently this is the number of distinct edge sets; i.e. the number of subsets of $$\big\{\{a,b\}:a,b \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \text{ and } a<b \big\}.$$

Note this counts labelled graphs, e.g., when $n=3$ we have the graphs:

[image: The 8 labelled graphs on the vertex set {1,2,3}]

We see that several of them are essentially the same, i.e., they are isomorphic.  The number of non-isomorphic (structurally inequivalent) graphs is given by Sloane's [A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088).